# Nginx Location Starts With But Not End With

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-lookarounds

I need a configuration

```
location ~ blabla {
    return 404;
}
```

/upload/a.jpg => must be returned 404,

/upload/a.jpg?letmein => must be OK.

any idea ?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I dont want to let users access photos directly over browser like : "http://blabla.com/upload/a.jpg". But I want to let them access like "http://blabla.com/upload/a.jpg?letmein" etc.

Comment: Have you tried [http_referrer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html)?

Comment: If I visit "blabla.com/upload.a.jpg" DIRECTLY, there will be no http_referer .

Comment: You tagged this with regex, are you looking for a regex that satisfies these path requirements?

Comment: @JasonL. for starting, yes.